# Error While get Some Data From Ajax Select2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-select2

I want get some value from ajax select2 but i have difficulty for get value i try code this but in the my textinput is show [Object Object]

```
$('.find_rm').select2({
    placeholder: 'Search With Name or No.',
    ajax: {
      url: 'sc_no_rm',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      processResults: function(data) {
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              text: item.pasien_name, //show name
              textSx: item.pasien_sx,
              textDate: item.pasien_date,
              textAddress: item.pasien_addr,
              id: item.pasien_no_rm
            }

          })
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
  });


  $('#no_rm').on('change', function(e) {
      console.log(this.textjk),
    // var data = e.params.data;
    // $("#pasien_name").val($(this).find('option:selected').text(this.))
    // $("#pasien_name").val($(this).slug())
       $("#pasien_name").val($(this).val(this.textSx))

  });
```

I hope my question is understandable..so Thank You... ;)

Comment: Did you try stringifying the parsed object?

Comment: Can you please `console.log(jQuery(this).val());` please

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt
I'm not sure what, but the point is to show results from ajax :)

Comment: @MayankDudakiya yes.. i can,how i get all result to inputtext?

Comment: @ACode Add `console.log(data);` after this line `processResults: function(data) {`

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui yes.. yes all data is displayed but i want to all data from selected

Comment: Please share your select2 part of HTML and the ajax response.